# SQL beginner question: unexpected behavior with where exists select 1

Tags: sql

I started using SQL a week ago. I am sorry but I have a "why my code does not work" question.

Please look at the following three queries on table1 and table2.

A. Inner join (returned 2 row results)

```
select t1.*, t2.* from table1 t1, table2 t2 
where t1.item = t2.item 
and t1.something = t2.something
```

B. Subquery (returned 2 row results)

```
select t1.* from table1 t1 
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 
                  where t1.item = t2.item 
                  and t1.something = t2.something)
```

C. My code (Expected the same results as in A. "Inner join" but takes forever to return results)

```
select t1.*, t2.* from table1 t1, table2 t2 
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2
                  where t1.item = t2.item 
                  and t1.something = t2.something)
```

For your reference, # of rows for each table is the following.

```
select count(*) from table1 -- (100K)
select count(*) from table2 -- (10K)
```

Would somebody kindly educate me know why my code (C) does not work?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: If you're just picking up SQL, you've chosen to learn it from a **really** bad guide/tutorial. Comma joins were obsoleted over **25** years ago, and whilst it took some time for every product to update to the standard, any one you use today will have updated decades ago.

Comment: `select t1.*, t2.* from table1 t1, table2 t2` in your third query generates a cross join between the two tables which results in an intermediate result of 1000000000 rows  - something that would not have happened if you had been using an explicit `JOIN` operator

Comment: @PhamX.Bach - most RDBMSs allow you to freely reuse aliases within subqueries. If there's a database that produces an error on this code, I don't think it conforms to the SQL standard.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever a, thanks, my wrong guess.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your (C) query is that the *outer* reference to `table2` is completed *unconstrained*<sup>1</sup>. This means that you're effectively writing query B again but also *cross joining* that result to `table2`, meaning that you'll get not 2 results but 20000.

You should be using explicit join syntax. One of the advantages of this is that it forces you to think about the join conditions *at the point of joining* rather than having to remember to include them in the general `where` clause.

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 
on t1.item = t2.item 
and t1.something = t2.something
```

It's an *error* to omit the `on` clause. It's never an error to forget to constrain a column in the `where` clause<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>Just because you refer to `table2` again inside your `exists` subquery, and even though you assign it the same `t2` alias, that doesn't mean that they are the *same* reference. The two references to `table2` are unrelated in any way.

<sup>2</sup>Of course, it's often a *logical error* to do this, but what I mean in this paragraph is specifically about error messages that the system will raise.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for the answer and useful comments. I have been trying to pick up SQL from other people's codes but I will buy a book to learn SQL properly. Thanks again everyone.